# How to moveactivity in background in android?

Tags: android

I have an App in which I am implemented **onBackPressed** but when I press onBack it will finish the activity by calling finish(),

its ok it will work fine ,but when I press device home button it will also finish activity,what I want **onBcakpressed** it will finish activity and when press device home button it will move that activity in back stack .How can I do that

**code is:-**

```
private long lastPressTime = 1;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((currentTime - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lastPressTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

First take a boolean

> boolean mBacktwice = false;

**On BackPressed**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (mBacktwice) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}

this.mBacktwice = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mBacktwice=false;                       
    }
}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all device home button never finish the activity. It design to go on home. All the application on running state is being in the backstack. And your activity will be call **onPause()**.

About your problem I am guessing that you may be calling onBackPressed() or finish() from the onPause().

Due to this only your activity is getting finish all time

Comment: I agree, I was writing the same answer

Comment: post code of onPause, onResume, or complete code if possible